# Observe runs multiple times on button click for the second time

Tags: android, kotlin

On my `SignInActivity` there's a button click listener (`signInButton.setOnClickListener`) that triggers the retrieval of an authentication token using `signInViewModel.getAuthToken(query)`

The problem is that multiple clicks on the button result in the observer running multiple times, causing multiple toasts to be displayed.

Code:

```
signInButton.setOnClickListener{
            val query: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()
            query["email"] = signInEmail.text.toString()
            query["password"] = signInPassword.text.toString()
            signInViewModel.getAuthToken(query)
            signInViewModel.signInResponse.observe(this, {
                response->  when(response){
                is NetworkResult.Success ->{
                    response.data?.let { Toast.makeText(this, it.access, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
                }

                is NetworkResult.Error ->{
                    Toast.makeText(this, response.message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                is NetworkResult.Loading -> {

                }
                }
            })
            
        }
```

Here is an example let's suppose in the first try I wrote my password wrong and it only runs once, but then after that if I click it again it runs multiple time by creating multiple toasts in this example.

Comment: For every click you add a new observer to `signInResponse`, so at the second click there will be two observers, thus the code in the lambda will be executed twice. You should put the `observe` outside of the click listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @gpunto says, you're adding a new `Observer` every click, so they're stacking up and each one fires when the `LiveData` updates.

But really, the observer doesn't have anything to do with the actual click anyway, it just receives updates to `signInResponse` and displays a thing. The click just calls `getAuthToken` with the current query. If doing that *happens* to cause a `signInResponse` update, then you have everything wired up to react to that event. But the Activity doesn't need to know how all that stuff works, or be written so one thing follows another.

That's a *reactive* pattern, where your UI is really just sending events (like `getAuthToken` when there's a click) and then reacting to other events so it can display them. By separating these things, you get a simple system that Just Works, and can react to updates no matter what caused them (e.g. a click, or restoring state) without having to write code to handle each case.

---

That said, this is a slightly tricky case because you have an event you want to *consume*. If you just set up that observer on `signInResponse`, it will fire every time you get a value for that `LiveData`. And that includes when the Activity is recreated (e.g. on rotation), `observe`s the `LiveData`, and gets the current (last-set) value. Basically, if you show a Toast, the same Toast will appear every time the Activity is recreated. That would be fine for setting the current value on a `TextView`, but it's bad for a popup that should only appear **once**.

[This is the current official recommendation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide/ui-layer/events#consuming-trigger-updates) for handling this situation. They're creating a UI state, which basically holds everything that needs to be displayed, including any popup messages (which acts like a queue, which is useful!). When the UI displays a message, it basically tells the `ViewModel` it's done so, and that handles removing the message from the state.

You could just implement this your own way, even if it's something simple like a `clearResponse()` function in your VM that clears the current value when you've seen it. It really depends on your app and what state you need to maintain. [Here's some other examples](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) from the Android devs - but like it says at the top, this advice is deprecated following the recommendations I linked earlier